# Jupyter - Python 3 - InvalidArgumentException while using "webdriver.Chrome()"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler, jupyter

I'm trying to use webdriver.Chrome() to open the chrome browser,

Its successful but cannot access the url variable.

[image: All the code and message]

Chrome popup but cannot access the url

[image]

I use this Chrome driver version 92 for windows:

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=92.0.4515.43/

```
pip install selenium    
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
print('-Finish importing package')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "youtube.com"
driver.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give the https/http protocol with the URL, so it should be like below.

`url = "https://youtube.com"`

**Code**

```
pip install selenium    
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
print('-Finish importing package')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://youtube.com"
driver.get(url)
```

[#Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name)